Double-syncs in a TCP communication
One of my co-workers had some odd output on some Wireshark logs with "connecting twice". I went and looked, and sure enough it looks like the client redoing the opening TCP handshake sequence, less than a second later.

The client side in this case is 3rd party software. The server side is our own software. Apparently, our code on the other end of our socket calls is only seeing one connection and only getting data from the first (shorter) one.
I find it odd that there are several instances in here for the client sending 2 packets with the same sequence and only getting one ack back. I find it odder that the last packet from the client (#7) before it apparently starts over (on packet #8) is not ACKed, and it appears to be very close to 0.05 seconds between the two.
I'm a bit of a neophyte at reading TCP logs though (I'm really much more used to UDP), so I'm wondering if all this is normal?

There's only one handshake in each TCP connection - the normal SYN-SYN/ACK-ACK.
What you mistake for a double handshake is another socket connection, as indicated by the differing initiator (client) port number.
You can't have more than one SYN per connection and direction. Issuing a second SYN should result in a RST. Connecting and synchronizing TCP sockets is defined in RFC 9293.

Ah yes. This is indeed the issue. For some reason our local server isn't reposting the listen. Which is of course an us issue. Its moderately well-exercised code, but it is a library so us not using it correctly is probably the culprit.
